# Displaying Prime Numbers Using document.write()

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment for school that I seem to be stuck on.

> Write a script that prints the prime numbers between 1 and 999 in a table that consists >of 10 columns.  Use document.write() statements to create the table elements and a >counter variable to create the table so that it consists of 10 columns. The counter >variable should start with an initial value of 0 and be incremented by one each time your >code identifies a prime number and prints it in a table cell. Once the counter variable >reaches a value of 10 (meaning that 10 cells have been added to the current row), print >to start a new row and reset the variable to 0.

I cannot figure out where my error or errors are with the table row and counter.  Also, I might have placed the document.write() methods in the wrong places.  Currently, the table only displays vertically.

Here is what I have:

```
<script>
    function primeNumbers(num) {
        document.write('<table>');
        if (num < 2) 
            return false;
        for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   
    document.write('<tr>');
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        if (primeNumbers(i)) {
            if (counter % 10 == 0) {
                document.write('</tr><tr>');
                counter = 0;
                }
            counter++;
            document.write('<td>' + i + '</td>');
        }
    }
    document.write('</table>');
</script>
```

Please, push me in the right direction and don't give me the answer.  I want to see if I can figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is completely separate out the detection of prime numbers from any kind of document writing.  Essentially write an `isPrimeNumber` function that doesn't do any doc writing

Comment: JaredPar, I just added document.write('<table><tr>'); above the counter variable.  So far looking better... :)

Comment: In this case it's hard to say where your problem is just "pushing your to the right direction".

Comment: You aren't closing off the last row.  Missing `</tr>` for the last row.

Comment: I figured it out!! I had the code correct, except the document.write('<table>') placement.  Thank you, JaredPar.  My dumb error on my part was my css.  I had table border:1px solid black. I forgot to add table row (tr).

Comment: jfriend00, good eye! I didn't notice that! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your code:

- The `<table>` opener was inside the function, so actually it was opening 1000 times.
- The counter is reset, so you don't need to use modulus (`%`), just compare to 10.
- A `</tr>` was missing in the end
- Your function `primeNumbers` is misnamed, the best would be call `isPrime`

Here's the code:

```
function isPrime(num) {
    if (num < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

document.write("<table><tr>");
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        if (counter == 10) {
            document.write('</tr><tr>');
            counter = 0;
        }
        counter++;
        document.write('<td>' + i + '</td>');
    }
}
document.write('</tr></table>');
```

Here's the fiddle working (I can't use document.write here, but you get the idea) http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/D2bzk/

Comment: Thank you, ariel.  I didn't even think about the modulus.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezn7f/

```
<script>
function primeNumbers(num) {
    if (num < 2) 
        return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
document.write('<table><tr>');
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    if (primeNumbers(i)) {

        if (counter % 10 == 0) {
            document.write('</tr><tr>');
            counter = 0;
        }
         counter++;
         document.write('<td>' + i + '</td>');
    }
}
document.write('</table>');
</script>
```

I wonder if this is what you are looking for though. I didn't change much in your code.